# How do I check how much total memory my VM has?

Tags: memory, proc

I've tried /proc/meminfo but my permission has been denied.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `ls -l /proc/meminfo` to your question?

Comment: You need to provide more information when asking questions. Assuming you mean Linux, you can run the 'free' command to see the total memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `cat /proc/meminfo`, not execute `/proc/meminfo` directly.

The reason you get "permission denied" is because you're trying to execute /proc/meminfo, and /proc/meminfo has no executable bit set (because it's not an executable, it's a file that you have to read).

Reading /proc/meminfo itself should not require any special permissions.

You might find it easier to find the total memory using the `free` command, though.